# How to organize the build-process with Makefiles for Code in several directories

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

**My Fortran-Code is structured as follows:**

There are two folders (with several subdirectories)

1.

```
/home/user/general_part
```

where some very general files are located and which should be used in several versions of the program.
**files:** (with relative path)

- mainsubdir/main.F

- subdir1/file1.F

- subdir1/headerfile1.h

2.

```
/home/user/special_part/special_case1
```

where the files located which are case-dependend.

**files:** (with relative path)

- subdir2/file2.F

- subdir2/headerfile2.h

- subdir3/file3.F

---

**How could I organize the build-process?**

**Should I use several makefiles in each of the directories?** 
**Where should the object-files be located (especially the ones from the general files)?**

My aim would be that I can start the build-process from the directory:

```
/home/user/special_part/special_case
```

with a simple *make* or a little script.

So at the end it should be possible that I can build a program always with the general files from 1. and several special-case files located in:

```
/home/user/special_part/special_case1
/home/user/special_part/special_case2
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why nobody is answering, is probably because the question is too general.  Be more specific.

Say something like: "this is the program I want to build, and this is my makefile, please critique my makefile".

1. You can organize it any way you like, as long as it's logical and consistent.  I put some beginner guidelines at

   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19816058/makefile-fibonacci/19821801#19821801
2. No.  Make is really designed and works best, with a single makefile.  You can have relevant makefile *fragments* in each directory, which are included in the main makefile.  Do not have complete makefiles in each subdirectory.  Google for the classic paper "Recursive make considered harmful" to see why that is so.
3. You can place your result anywhere you want, some people, place results alongside sources, some, in a separate directory.  Just place results in some logical and consistent way.  Same goes for intermediate files, such as object files.

Comment: Thanks for pointing to this paper. It is really worth the read.

Comment: @P.R. What is worth noting, is that there is a place for recursive make - when you have a self-contained module you bring in from the outside. I cover that in my guidelines. The problem is, once you start integrating and merging it with your own code in other directories, at that point, you should also integrate the makefiles in that module, that is, convert them to be included in your big makefile. Most companies fail to do that as they continue with recursive make. You have to make a choice, either keep the module completely separate, or integrate the build system, can't have it both ways.

Comment: We are using a monolithic repository and all I am making currently is within it. So I went for the include approach. What we are building at the moment is minimal however, as there are mainly a few Cython files. I have one comment. Your guidelines are not accessible for me. It looks like the original question got deleted.

Comment: @P.R.Marcus, although technically GNU Make can do any computation you want, it is really not designed for what you are trying to force it to do. There are much better tools for that, such as Python or C.

GNU Make is designed to efficiently construct files, typically using some "source" files. Source files, are the ones you edit yourself, and that are in a version control system.

Instead, you are trying to get it to print stuff.

Comment: @P.R.Here is that answer, in several comments:Marcus, although technically GNU Make can do any computation you want, it is really not designed for what you are trying to force it to do. There are much better tools for that, such as Python or C.

GNU Make is designed to efficiently construct files, typically using some "source" files. Source files, are the ones you edit yourself, and that are in a version control system.

Instead, you are trying to get it to print stuff.

Good practices for a beginner to follow are:

Start with "all" target.

Comment: @P.R.It is an "abstract" or "phony" target, which means it does not really represent a single file that is constructed, but (typically), a collection of files.

Phony targets may depend (or "have prerequsites") on further phony targets and/or real targets (single files).

Real targets, if they are not sources, may further depend only on real targets, not on phonies.

Everything eventually depends on real files which are source. Sources do not depend on anything further.

Phonies and sources do not have recipes.

Comment: @P.R.Intermediate real files always have a recipe, and that recipe is supposed to write one file and one file only - its target.

Recursive make, using $(MAKE) is to be used only in one case. And that is, if you have some part of your system, which is "self-contained". That means, it does not use any anything (any sources or constructed files) outside of itself (but the outside may use it). Then you can use $(MAKE) for that part.